# How to toggle between true/false on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am using an `.on` click function to enable a setting. How would I modify this to say on click, toggle the `(true)` value from false to true and back again on the next click?

```
    $("#myBtn").on('click', function(){
            panorama.setVisible(true);
    });
```

Comment: Use `panorama.toggle();` or `$(panorama).toggle();`. Refer to http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: negate the current value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can achieve this by using a boolean

```
let isVisible = true;
$("#myBtn").on('click', function(){
    panorama.setVisible(isVisible);
    isVisible = !isVisible;
});
```

So everytime you click it, `isVisible` will swap between `true` and `false`

Comment: Worked great! Thanks :)